# Strategies for encapsulating and/or organizing data

Tags: java, android, encapsulation

I have an app that is fairly average in size and data density, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to encapsulate the data, since it needs to be used in many places around the application.

Currently, I have all my data, options, and states stored in a big "DataObject". It looks something like this:

```
public class DataObject {
  public static final String M_READY_INTENT = "com.intent.action.M_READY"
  //and more...
  public static jsonRawFoos;
  public static jsonRawBars;
  //and more..
  private static HashMap<String, Foo> catFoos = new HashMap<>();
  private static HashMap<String, Bar> catBars = new HashMap<>();
  //and more..
  private static String session;
  //and more..
  private static boolean optFoo;
  //and more..
  public static boolean dataState = false;
  //and more..

  /* Static accessors,  static data processors */
}
```

This sums up to 42 member fields. These must be accessible in several different Activities and Classes across my application. I've considered just creating a local instance in my `MainActivity` and simply interfacing `MainActivity` to get access to the `DataObject`, but I'm not sure that passing an interface everywhere is the correct option.

To sum up my question, what is the best approach to encapsulating/organizing my data in order to make it available in multiple different objects while keeping my code clean, memory efficient, and safe from crashes during pause/resume/suspend events?

**Edit:**

To add more detail, my app makes API requests to get lists of 3 different kinds of objects, we'll call them `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Cat`. The result of these calls are in JSON format, so after the `IntentService` comes back with the results of the API call, `DataObject` parses the JSON and stores the generated objects in `HashMap`s.

The generated lists objects need to be accessed by adapters in `Fragments` contained in `MainActivity`. There are also other activities that occasionally need access to these lists of objects.

In addition, the user can set certain options that affect one or many of the `Fragment`s and `Activity`s across the application. I put those settings in the `DataObject` also.

Finally, the application occasionally needs to know what data is ready and whether other certain states have been cleared before determining the next course of action. I save these states in the `DataObject` as well.

**Second Edit:**

I forgot to mention, the `DataObject` also has the responsibility of informing the rest of the application when certain data has become available.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what your data looks like? I think this is a valid question, but without some more detail I think it's hard to come up with a solution. 

In situations like this, I find myself usually asking questions about what makes sense to group together, how things relate to each other, who needs to use these objects, etc. Without knowing specifically what "DataObject' needs to be responsible for, I think you might end up with some vague answers. Right off the bat this looks like the god object anti pattern, but I need some context.

Comment: Well, I think that's actually my problem. DataObject isn't responsible for a specific thing, it just holds, organizes, and operates on the data in my app. I'll try to add more detail without making my post a gigantic bloated mess.

Comment: I hear you. Definitely sounds like you may have a god object situation - one object that knows too much: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object

Comment: That's definitely the feeling I've been having in the back of my head. At first I tried to fight it, but it ended up making my data feel disjointed and I was calling the data from all over my application just to form one statement, it felt messy. But, that doesn't mean the way I'm doing it now is the right way. I'm just not sure how to assess the situation differently than I am at the moment.

Comment: Based on the edit, one thing I would definitely look at is separating JSON deserialization from your DataObject class. It sounds like you have handful of deserialization methods to generate your Foo, Bar, and Cat objects given some JSON. You can write mappers to do this, or possibly even use something like Jackson to do it for you. This object seems like it combines state management and data retrieval into one place, which to me are two different concerns.

Comment: So, the way my parsing works is that my `IntentService` gets data and informs my `DataObject`, my `DataObject` spins up a thread and uses a method built into the `Foo`, `Bar`, or `Cat` object to generate a new `Foo`, `Bar`, or `Cat` object, depending on which JSON data became available. The parsing method is contained in the object which the JSON pertains to. So the data goes `API>Service>DataObject>Thread>BuildObjMapLoop>Cat/Foo/Bar.build(JSONObject)` then the `HashMap` is stored in the `DataObject`

Answer (score 1):

**[Cohesion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) and [Coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) are 2 important concept in order make a good OO design you are trying.**

Cohesion should be more concerning to you because that's what will drive the decision on how to organize the data.

Key questions you need to ask yourself are like (*since you haven't provided all the data so you need to think and ask yourself*):

- Are these fields related to each other
- Do these fields possibly define the state of an object

Based on what the type of fields and their purpose, you may choose to make classes or keep them in single class.

Looking at the same code you have provided, you have made everything static and fields doesn't look like defining state of an object or class, so probably keeping them in one class looks fine but one thing you can do is divide the data in 2 classes, make one more class like `ApplicationConstants` and put all constants like `static final String M_READY_INTENT = "com.intent.action.M_READY"` in that class.

> I've considered just creating a local instance in my MainActivity and
>   simply interfacing MainActivity to get access to the DataObject, but
>   I'm not sure that passing an interface everywhere is the correct
>   option.

You have made everything static so why you even want to create an object of your `DataObject` class, just access all the fields using static getter and setter methods.

---

Updated based on OP's edit.

*Disclaimer: I don't all your fields of the DataObject class and their purpose, so below design is based on information provided*

Looks like you need to have 3 different classes to maintain the state of what you call Foo, Bar and Cat.

So, keep this `DataObject` class as your super class and have fields in it which doesn't require a unique state, so:

```
public class DataObject {
  public static final String M_READY_INTENT = "com.intent.action.M_READY"
  // Code for informing the rest of the application when certain data has become available. Could be static ...
  //Anything else which is not unique and is not dependent on Foo, Cat or Bar...
}
```

Then create your 3 new classes which will hold the state, sample `FooDataObject`

```
public class FooDataObject extends DataObject {
     public jsonRawFoo;
      public HashMap<String, Foo> catFoos = new HashMap<>();
      public String session;
      public boolean optFoo;
      public boolean dataState = false;
      //Etc... more methods and getter/setter ...
}


public class BarDataObject extends DataObject {
     public jsonRawBar;
      public HashMap<String, Foo> catBars = new HashMap<>();
      public String session;
      public boolean optBar;
      public boolean dataState = false;
      //Etc... more methods and getter/setter ...
}
```

So, basically anything which is global state will end up as a field in `DataObject`, and anything which is specific state will end up as a field in `FooDataObject` or `CatDataObject` or `BarDataObject`.

Comment: Good comments.  Perhaps an advantage to having a reference to an object in the main activity class (or Application class) is it might be easier to refactor or redesign later.

Comment: I meant for the line to convey that I've been considering making everything **not** static, making a local instance in my MainActivity to access through an interface. Sorry for the confusion. I figured that that way, the `DataObject` would be more secure in terms of the changing state of the application.

Comment: I've been mulling over the "Are these fields related to each other?" question for awhile. It's difficult since `Bar` and `Cat` objects are just organizational representations of collections of `Foo`s. They feel like they're all related. Maybe more soul-searching is required.

Comment: Your edit is interesting. Is this separation for the sake of readability? I'm not clear on the advantages of organizing the data this way.

Comment: You said "*To add more detail, my app makes API requests to get lists of 3 different kinds of objects*". How you are going to maintain the state of 3 different object without having different classes ?? Read the last statement of my answer.

Comment: Also in future if you are want to support one more type, lets say Zoo, and you want state management later then how will you manage without this ?? You need to start with scalability in mind.

Comment: So what you decided and how you did it ??